# Does PHP use $$ with exec(), and how can I preserve it for the next script?

Tags: php, bash

I use PHP `exec()` to start a process in Bash that has `$$` in its commandline. When using PHP though, PHP itself seems to take the variable `$$` instead of letting Bash use it in the script.

Does PHP use this variable? Assuming so, how do I preserve it for the Bash script?

Example: `exec('echo $$')` performs `echo 1538` in Bash, not `echo $$`, since PHP seems to have taken the variable $$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Php would not 'take' the `$$` value, since it's inside a single-quoted string.

It's bash converting it to the PID of the bash process handling your echo command.

If you want to literally output two `$` via the echo command, you'll have to escape them:

```
exec('echo \\$\\$');
```

followup:

```
marc@panic:~$ bash
marc@panic:~$ echo $$
31285
marc@panic:~$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo exec('echo $$');
31339
php > echo exec('echo \\$\\$');
$$
```

followup 2:

```
marc@panic:~$ cat pid
#!/bin/bash
echo $$
marc@panic:~$ ./pid    <--new shell started to execute script
31651
marc@panic:~$ . pid    <---script executed within context of current shell
31550
marc@panic:~$ echo $$
31550
```

Comment: "In a Bash script, it doesn't do this" - yes it does.

Comment: bash subsitutes variables before executing the command. are you nitpicking or just don't get it?

Comment: Your script is working exactly as specified. `echo $$` is passed down to bash, which parses the $$ and properly converts it to the PID of the bash process, which is then output by echo. This output is then returned to PHP as the output of the exec() call. Also remember that the shell parses variables BEFORE executing whatever the command is.

Comment: they don't start a screen session. screen requires a terminal, and exec() from php won't have one. bash script run from the command runs within the context of the shell that the script is running in. php's firing up a brand NEW bash to handle the echo.

Comment: It doesn't give the terminal's PID, it gives you the pid of the bash shell. It's hard to figure out what your problem is, you haven't mentioned any of this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As @marc said exec is actually returning the PID of the process.

However this is still "dodgy" syntax to use in PHP since you must be careful to place it in `''` otherwise PHP will do something special with it. Basically PHP has the ability to use variables in two ways:

```
$a
```

and:

```
$$a
```

The latter using the value of $a to actually arrive to a new variable name, so you gotta be careful about how you use that syntax (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath No using `$$` is